# Azure Template Deployment via powershell: "Template parameter JToken type is not valid"

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-deployment, azure-rm-template

I am attempting to deploy a virtual machine via Powershell using ARM Templates.

I want to pass the SSH public key into the template using Template Parameters.

The parameters are defined in the template file as so:

```
    "parameters": {
        "sshPublicKey": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
```

And here is the powershell script where I load the public key from a file and add it as a template parameter.

```
$publicKey = (Get-Content .\keys\id_rsa.pub)

"Public Key is string of length {0}" -f $publicKey.Length

$parametersObject = @{"sshPublicKey" = $publicKey }

"Running the Deployment now"
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateFile .\template.json -TemplateParameterObject $parametersObject
```

I get the following frustrating error:

> New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 9:02:09 AM - Error:
>   Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed:
>   'Template parameter JToken type is not valid. Expected 'String, Uri'.
>   Actual 'Object'. Please see
>   https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for usage details.'.
>   At
>   C:\users\sheph\Documents\GitHub\aspnet-core-linux-exercise\setup-ubuntu-nginx\deploy.ps1:20
>   char:1
>   + New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName - ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

At first I thought it was an issue with the string length. (The key has a length of 402 characters). But then if I replaced it with 402 consecutive 'A' characters I don't get the error.

I have another example which uses a template parameter file rather than a template parameter object, and this works too.

Is there a way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that my $publicKey value contained a newline character.

I fixed it by calling the `Trim` method.

```
$publicKey = (Get-Content .\keys\id_rsa.pub);
$publicKey = $publicKey.Trim();
$parametersObject = @{"sshPublicKey" = $publicKey }
```

Comment: that is a generic error when the input fails to get casted to what arm template engine expects it to be, so just trimming everything when you have this error won't really help (usually)